# React - Is it poor form to have a lot of logic in render()?

Tags: reactjs

So,I've got a component called a `Project`, which has a child called `ProjectDates`.`ProjectDates` receives its parent's start/end dates, and calculates the percentage completion.

I'm currently doing this calculation in `render()` so that I don't have to do it both in `componentDidUpdate` and `componentDidMount`. Is that correct, or is there a more appropriate lifecycle hook that I should be using?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "logic" but no, you shouldn't put all the logic in `render`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think all your suggestions are in general wrong. Lets take them one by one:

1) **componentWillMount**. You can have some logic here - but it is [not recommended](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount) to introduce any side dependencies here. So in really world when you usually have to interact with back end - its of little help. Must better choice - [componentDidMount](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) where you do not have such restrictions.

2) **componentWillUpdate**. You should be careful here - to not end up with endless loop. Calling `setState` here [is prohibited](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillupdate) as it might in calling `componentWillUpdate` again and so on. Consider using [componentWillReceiveProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops).

3) **render**. This method should not contain any other logic except the one that prepares (renders) the content of the component. Consider moving your "business" logic to `componentWillReceiveProps`/`componentDidMount` or maybe constructor if applicable.

I recommend to go through the official [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html) before making decisions about your architecture.

Comment: Sorry, I think I might've worded that poorly. Does it make more sense now? This doesn't seem to be covered in the docs.

Comment: Now you methods looks more appropriate. Except for the fact - that no `logic` should be present in `render`. If you are worried about code duplication in `componentDidUpdate` and `componentDidMount` - just move logic in separate class method and call it in both places.